# Ошибка в ajax запросе

Tags: ajax, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, вроде ошибки нет, а почему-то ругается постоянно.

```
function sendReply(commentID, userID, serverID){
    var messege = $('textarea[name="messege"]').val();
    $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"./lib/ajax.php",
          data: {commentID:commentID, messege:messege, userID:userID, serverID:serverID},
          cache: false,
          success: function(msg){
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
             location.reload();
           }
      })
}
```

Обработчик

```
include_once '../app/function.php';     
$commentID = $_POST['commentID']; //ID кооментария к которому ответ.
$messege = $_POST['messege'];
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$serverID = $_POST['serverID'];
sendReply($commentID, $messege, $userID, $serverID);
```

Постоянно пишет, что мол либо функция не определена (когда одна точка) либо что файл "../app/function.php" не найден (когда 2 точки).
Хотя функция определена.

Comment: у вас `sendReply()` определен только в js, значит.

Comment: А sendReply() определяется в `../app/function.php`?

Comment: Да, она там определяется

Answer (score 1):

В начале файла   в начале файла lib/ajax.php  заполни массив $_POST тестовыми данными и открой этот файл в браузере и уже разберись с ошибками.

Ajax тут как бэ нипричом )

Comment: Ошибок там нет, проверял все кучу раз уже, и что выводит в результате я написал.